# Android Parcelable finals

Tags: java, android, serialization, final, parcelable

So, i have the following class, which i want to serialize using Android Parcelable

```
public class Parent{
   public static final int x; //primtive type
   public static final Animal y; //another percelable
   public static final String z; //object type
   public class Inner{
       public static final int a; //primtive type
       public static final Animal b; //another percelable
       public static final String c; //object type
   }
   private int classIntState; //primtive type
   private Animal classAnimalState; //another percelable
   private String classObjectState; //object type
}
```

I know the drills for class variables. but having trouble with finals and finals from inner classes.

Done some additional research, and i looked into [BlutoothDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) class, which happens to be also Parcelable and have bunch of constants.

And, i found this on source code,

```
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<BluetoothDevice> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<BluetoothDevice>() {
    public BluetoothDevice createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new BluetoothDevice(in.readString());
    }
    public BluetoothDevice[] newArray(int size) {
        return new BluetoothDevice[size];
    }
   };

   public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
       out.writeString(mAddress);
   }

   BluetoothDevice(String address) {
        getService();  // ensures sService is initialized [nothing to do with parcelable]
        if (!BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(address)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(address + " is not a valid Bluetooth address");
        }

        mAddress = address;
    }
```

Seems like these guys are completely ignoring all those finals/Constants from their Parcelable implementation.

This puzzle me a bit, so looked into how Java Serialize finals and found this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904560/how-does-java-serialization-deserialize-final-fields-when-no-default-constructor) on stack overflow. What i understood from their is , it is done by JVM using reflection. Then i looked into [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) and [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) source and doesn't seems like anywhere finals are handles explicitly.

Do i have to, or i do not have to? What really am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems like these guys are completely ignoring all those finals/Constants from their Parcelable implementation.

Well, if you look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java) for `BluetoothDevice`, you'll notice that all of the `final` variables are defined outside the constructor. So when `return new BluetoothDevice(in.readString())` is called, all the `final` variables **outside** the constructor definition are initialized to their respective values, and then the constructor `BluetoothDevice(String address)` is called.

What I'm trying to say is that those values are not written or read from the `Parcel`. They are simply initialized by the class right before the constructor is called by the `CREATOR` of `Parent` (although you haven't defined one in your question's `Parent` source code).

Now, let's say you initialize the values of the `final` variables based on the parameters in a parameterized constructor. For example,

```
public Parent(int x, Animal y, String z) {

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;

}
```

**In THAT case** you'll need to write `x`, `y` and `z` to the `Parcel` in `writeToParcel()` just as you would any `non-final` value.

Then in your `Parent` class' `CREATOR`:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Parent> CREATOR =
    new Parcelable.Creator<Parent>() {
    public Parent createFromParcel(Parcel in) {

        //read values from Parcel
        int intParam = in.readInt();
        Animal animalParam = in.readParcelable(Animal.class.getClassLoader());
        String stringParam = in.readString();

        //create parent
        Parent parent = new Parent(intParam, animalParam, stringParam);

        return parent;
    }
    public Parent[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Parent[size];
    }
 };
```

That is, you read the values of the variables, and then use the constructor to assign them. Again, this is pretty much almost the same as if the variables weren't `final`. I don't think it makes any difference that they are.