# How does Flink handle final fields in a POJO during deserialization?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In my Flink graph, I have certain POJO classes with final fields.  These fields are set in an overloaded constructor.  Example, I have a Car POJO with final fields, and a HybridCar class that derives from Car as shown below.

```
public class Car {
   private final int year;
   private final int modelNumber;

   public Car (int year, int modelNumber) {
       this.year = year;
       this.modelNumber = modelNumber;
   }
}

public HybridCar extends Car {

    private final int powerInWatts;

    public HybridCar(int powerInWatts, int year, int modelNumber) {
        super(year, modelNumber);
        this.powerInWatts = powerInWatts;
    }
}
```

Will this work for Flink?  That is, will Flink be able to deserialize this class using its internal serialization/deserialization library?

A [related SO question/answer on JVM deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904589) says that the JVM "Deserialization is implemented by the JVM on a level below the basic language constructs. Specifically, it does not call any constructor."  (or more correctly, it only calls the super class constructor.